# In Yocto image recipe could I include another image recipes

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have 3 image recipes

***image_base.bb***

***image_tools.bb***

***image_prod.bb***

I've try to make next workflow:

**image_base.bb**

```
# base config
IMAGE_INSTALL +="tool1"
```

**image_tools.bb**

```
require image_base.bb
# add additional 
IMAGE_INSTALL += "tool2"
```

**image_prod.bb**

```
require image_tools.bb
# add final 
IMAGE_INSTALL +="tool3"
```

My expectations are in prod image we will have tool1, tool2, tool3
That works for image tools - tool1 + tool2 are in image.
But can't execute tool2 in prod image.
According bitbake installed_packages.txt all are included

Am I missing something ?

Comment: you have errors in you example syntax..I will edit it..